# Possible to get the code behind the "Request Tracking immediately" button on the Triggerred Send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi

It seems that the IERs do not always appear automatically and we must often manually click on the "Request Tracking immediately" button present on the Triggered Send linked to the send to get them.
We would like to set up an automation on Salesforce to retrieve IERs automatically once or twice a day without having to click on this button. Would it be possible to retrieve the code behind the button or a code or article to set this up?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to „get” that code, you’d have to write a bunch of queries to call SFMC APIs to achieve this.

And I do not see any need to do that, as the frequency of updating Sales Cloud with tracking data is set in:

Sales Cloud > Marketing Cloud tab > Marketing Cloud Connector Settings > Tracking > Tracking Frequency

[image]

The default is "Hourly", which means that the IER should be created within an hour of the send. If this isn’t working as expected, I’d create a support case.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, even if the Tracking Frequency is defined on Hourly, we need to often click on "Request Tracking immediately" button to get all the EIR. They are not always automatically displayed. We opened a case and the solution given by Support was to click on that button to get all the available IER.